# How to avoid the AWS/Glue Catalog Tables change the columns data type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have tables defined (via CF) in this way on my Glue catalogs:

```
MyTable:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    DependsOn : RealyseCatalogDB
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseName: !Ref CatalogDatabaseName
      TableInput:
        Name: 'customers'
        Description: Some test data
        TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
        Parameters: {
          "skip.header.line.count": "1",
          "compressionType": "none",
          "classification": "csv",
          "columnsOrdered": "true",
          "areColumnsQuoted": "true",
          "delimiter": ",",
          "typeOfData": "file"
        }
        StorageDescriptor:
          OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
          Columns:
            - Name: id
              Type: bigint
            - Name: startDate
              Type: date
            - Name: finalNumber
              Type: smallint
            - Name: price
              Type: int
            - Name: sumIndicator
              Type: tinyint
            - Name: officialName
              Type: string
          InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
          Location: !Sub ${SomewhereS3BasePath}/MyFile.csv
          SerdeInfo:
            SerializationLibrary: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde
```

In my Glue/Spark code I read data from that table using:

```
val df = spark.glueContext.getCatalogSource(
  database = "test-db",
  tableName = "customers"
).getDynamicFrame().toDF()
```

but the types `date`, `tinyint`, `smallint` are converted to strings instead of the equivalent Spark's types: `DateType`, `ByteType` and `ShortType`. So I am forcing to add:

```
df
  .withColumn("startDate",col("startDate").cast(DateType))
  .withColumn("finalNumber",col("finalNumber").cast(ShortType))
  .withColumn("sumIndicator",col("sumIndicator").cast(ByteType))
```

which defeats the purpose of define the table in CF. Is there any solution to avoid that? I tried with very simple test data with well defined values to avoid "resolveChoices" situations but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the limitation of OpenCSVSerde which treats all columns data types as strings [[1]](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde) . If you want desired data types for your columns  then you can achieve the same by leveraging Glue applyMapping transformation , refer to example [[2]](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/DataCleaningLambda.scala#L55).